# Symfony2 UniqueEntity not triggered and throwing db exception

Tags: php, symfony, unique-constraint

I'm having a problem with the UniqueEntity validation in a Symfony 2.8.8 project that is not triggered causing the db exception: 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7Nrl/JfB8E47D1ZtoryFsQ==' for key 'UNIQ_3BF9FEA896901F54'

The other validation rules works.

Here you are the validation.yml. The field with the constraint not triggered is "number".

```
AppBundle\Entity\UrinaryCytologicalExam:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [number]
            message: Il numero di referto è già presente nel db
    properties:
        age:
            - Type:
                type: integer
        acceptanceDate:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Date:
                message: La data inserita non è valida
        adequacySample:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Type:
                type: string
            - Length:
                min: 3
                max: 255
                minMessage: "Il campo deve contenere almeno {{ limit }} caratteri."
                maxMessage: "Il campo non può superare {{ limit }} caratteri."
        anatomicalSamplingSite:
            - Type:
                type: string
            - Length:
                min: 3
                max: 255
                minMessage: "Il campo deve contenere almeno {{ limit }} caratteri."
                maxMessage: "Il campo non può superare {{ limit }} caratteri."
        category:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Valid: ~
        clinicalInformation:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Type:
                type: string
        description:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Type:
                type: string
        number:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Regex:
                pattern: "/^(C|c)\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}$/"
                message: "Il numero di referto è composto dalla lettera C, uno spazio, 4 numeri, uno spazio, 4 numeri (es. C 2016 0008)"
        reportDate:
            - Date:
                message: La data inserita non è valida
        sampleDate:
            - Date:
                message: La data inserita non è valida
        submittedMaterial:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Campo obbligatorio
            - Type:
                type: string
        gynecologist:
            - Valid: ~
```

and the other essential files...

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * AppBundle\Entity\UrinaryCytologicalExam
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="urinary_cytological_exams")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UrinaryCytologicalExamRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class UrinaryCytologicalExam
{
    CONST EXAM_NAME = 'Esame citologico urinario';

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int $age
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $age;

    /**
     * @var datetime $acceptanceDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="acceptance_date", type="date", nullable = true)
     */
    private $acceptanceDate;

    /**
     * @var string $adequacySample
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="encrypted_string", length=255)
     */
    private $adequacySample;

    /**
     * @var string $anatomicalSamplingSite
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="encrypted_string", length=255)
     */
    private $anatomicalSamplingSite;

    /**
     * @var string $clinicalInformation
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="clinical_information", type="encrypted_text")
     */
    private $clinicalInformation;

    /**
     * @var string $description
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="encrypted_text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var boolean $isActive
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isActive = false;

    /**
     * @var boolean $isSampleDateNotAvailable
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isSampleDateNotAvailable;

    /**
     * @var string $number
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="encrypted_string", length=255, unique = true)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @var datetime $sampleDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sample_date", type="date", nullable = true)
     */
    private $sampleDate;

    /**
     * @var datetime $reportDate
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="report_date", type="date", nullable = true)
     *
     */
    private $reportDate;

    /**
     * @var string $submittedMaterial
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="submitted_material", type="encrypted_text")
     */
    private $submittedMaterial;


    /**
     * @var datetime $createdAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     *
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var Category $category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Core\UrinaryCytologicalExamParisSystem")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var Gynecologist $gynecologist
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gynecologist")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gynecologist_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $gynecologist;

    /**
     * @var PersonDetail $personDetail
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\PersonDetail", inversedBy="HPVExams")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_detail_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $personDetail;

    /**
     * @var User $user
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    //...    
}
```

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request,
    Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface,
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\UrinaryCytologicalExam;
use AppBundle\Utility\Uppercaser;

class UrinaryCytologicalExamFormHandler {

    private $entityManager;
    private $isClickedSubmitAndAddButton;
    private $session;
    private $uppercaser;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManager $entityManager,
        Session $session,
        Uppercaser $uppercaser
    )
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->uppercaser = $uppercaser;
    }

    public function handle(FormInterface $form, Request $request, $message)
    {
        if(!$request->isMethod('POST')) {
            return false;
        }

        $form->bind($request);

        $this->isClickedSubmitAndAddButton = ($form->get('submitAndAdd')->isClicked()) ? true : false;

        if(!$form->isValid()) {
            return false;
        }

        $exam = $form->getData();

        $this->persist($exam, $message);

        return true;
    }

    public function getIsClickedSubmitAndAddButton() {
        return $this->isClickedSubmitAndAddButton;
    }

    public function persist(UrinaryCytologicalExam $exam, $message)
    {
        $this->entityManager->persist($this->uppercaser->uppercase($exam));
        $this->entityManager->flush();

        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('success', $message);
    }
}
```

The same code is working with other entities...

Comment: Are you sure that number is actually the problem? `7Nrl/JfB8E47D1ZtoryFsQ==` doesn't look at all like `C 2016 0008`.

Comment: Yes, it is encrypted when persisted in the db. And decrypted when the value is shown on the screen. But this is not the problem, disabling the encryption is the same...